# How to make jump independent on FPS?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I almost made a 3D horror game in which the Player can walk, run and jump, but I noticed that jump depends on FPS. The more FPS, the higher the jump. I want to Player jump doesn't depend on FPS. How to solve the problem?
Script Player (just Update):

```
   void Update{
        // Jump when Player is on the Ground
        Ground = Physics.CheckSphere(GroundCheck.position, groundDistance, Groundmask);

        if (Ground && velocity.y < 0) { velocity.y = -0.5f; }

        posX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); posZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 Move = transform.right * posX + transform.forward * posZ;

        controller.Move(Move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity);

        if ((Input.GetMouseButton(0) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Return)) && Ground)
        {
            { velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(3 - gravity); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would say your issue is "velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;", you really want to detect the key down and just apply a set force and not to times it by Time.deltaTime (this creates the FPS related jump problem), maybe instead put a on keyup remove upwards force? to create short jumping

Comment: I solved the problem. I used void FixedUpdate(), changed some values, so jump works correctly. Anyway, thank you!